# Use of property of absolute value

Tags: absolute-value

Suppose inequality |2x-1|$\leq$x+1,

should the two cases to consider be

x$\leq$1/2 and
x$\geq$1/2  or  x$\geq$1/2 and x<1/2?

Comment: Either way you will get the same answer.

Comment: Actually, it doesn’t matter. Both cover all the possible cases, and lead to the same simplifications.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying